# "Failed to sign in" Google play game services

Tags: android, libgdx

I've now spent over 8 continuous hours trying to figure out what is wrong and I still have'nt found a solution. I added leaderboards and achievements to my libgdx android app, and published it in alpha. For some reason, when I try to sign in in game, I get the following popup: "Failed to sign in.Please check your network connection and try again". My SHA1 key is correct(I checked credentials in the developer console) and so is my client ID. I have no idea what is causing my problem. When I check logcat, I see this: GameHelper: onAR: responseCode=SIGN_IN_FAILED, so giving up.

I also added myself as a tester.

Does anyone know how to fix this?!

Comment: please post Manifest.

Comment: Did you create your client IDs from the "google developper console" (wrong way), or from the "Google Play Developper console" (correct) ? Also, do you have both a client ID with SHA1 key for your published version AND your debug version ?

Comment: Hi, I only have a client ID for my published version. How do I add one for my debug version?

Comment: Oh and here is my manifest http://pastebin.com/wydyWL9D

Comment: Hi, i added a link to a client ID with my debug key, but it still isn't working

Comment: Upon further observation, I realised I was getting the following error code: Application ID ************* is not associated with package com.henrYoda.dodgeit.android. Check the application ID in your manifest.

I have no idea what's causing this, because my application ID is the same as what I see in the google developer console

Comment: possible duplicate, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919040/android-connecting-to-google-play-still-gives-error-code-4/53986167#53986167)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out, it turns out that if your game is already published to alpha, you have to publish the leaderboards for them to work.(You cannot use them if they are ready for testing)

Comment: Hi, I also have the save problem. If I install by apk, it works, but if I install through google play(alpha version), I got the error. I've published leaderboards and achievements, still not working. Can you give me some details how to made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple clients ID registered in your Google Play Developer Console with the same client ID? If this happens, you can rename them.