# How to properly setup google play signin in Android?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I developed a game in android. I tried to implement the GooglePlay SignIn but it shows an error. I'm not able to debug this error. I tried installing the app in different phone models other than emulators.

Code:

```
public void startSignInIntent() {     
    startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
}

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task =
                    GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent);

            try {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            } catch (ApiException apiException) {
                String message = apiException.getMessage();
                if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                    message = getString(R.string.signin_other_error);
                }


                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setMessage(message)
                        .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                        .show();
            }

        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
```

[image: It Loads the GP Games]

[image: Then this happens]

**EDIT**

Now after following the suggested methods, the SignIn dialogue closes immediately without showing any errors.

Comment: I thenk the issue is task is executed asynchronously, it simply does not have result when you call 'getResult', what you want here is probably smth like 'awaitResult'.

Comment: @IcedLance Could you post a code for that?

Comment: Sry, on my phone but you can see it here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#blocking

Comment: I tried this but same problem.

Comment: Sorry, was wrong, your code is correct. But there're a couple other questionsbon StackOverflow about a very similar issue, maybe take a look at one of them like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919040/android-connecting-to-google-play-still-gives-error-code-4/28991289#28991289

Comment: Try to change your code to this:  `GoogleSignInResult task = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(intent);`. Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin#performing_interactive_sign-in) for more details.

Comment: @IcedLance Yea, I saw that too. I configured everything correctly.

Comment: @jess I changed according to the documentation. Now I get "There was an issue with Signin. Please try again later"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message of the `ApiException` is not really telling:

```
String message = apiException.getMessage();
```

To debug this, the status of the `ApiException` would rather be helpful:

```
int StatusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
```

See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin); It could have to do with oAuth2 scopes; but the question lacks the code where the `GoogleSignInClient` is being constructed (might be relevant to reproduce the error).

Another suspicion would be a missing or outdated [google-services.json](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592). It needs to have the matching (debug or release or both) key fingerprints added, of the keys used to sign that `APK` package. Even if not using Firebase, one has to setup the project there, in order to add the key fingerprints and to obtain that one config file (there has to be some `google_app_id` in the string resources and this is exactly what the [Play Services Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) would generate from that config file).

---

Status `4` means [SIGN_IN_REQUIRED](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes.html#SIGN_IN_REQUIRED):

> The client attempted to connect to the service but the user is not signed in.
>
> The client may choose to continue without using the API.

A failed authentication hints for `google_app_id` or the key fingerprints not matching. Think one does not require permission to get the currently signed-in Google account with the `GoogleSignInClient`... so this likely means, the API client not being signed in to Google Play.

Comment: Same error: code 4. 
I have already pasted debug and release keys to play console while linking.

Comment: Is there any way to delete the game from the games console and start from scratch?

Comment: @PSN you don't have to delete it from there, but instead have to link the accounts in between Firebase and the Play Console, plus the matching keys. Not up for a chat since it's 2am here and programmed all day.

Comment: I have setup Firebase and Play Console properly I guess. I gave both keys. Well, for release key I gave the google SHA1 since I opted for Gplay signing.

Comment: @PSN with Play signing one has to add up to 3 fingerprints; but adding the fingerprints API side does not help unless having the correct `google_app_id` in the sting resources (one can add it manually, too - but one can only get it from the `google-services.json`... at least have no clue where else to get it).

Comment: Google App ID is present in the Play Games Console right?

Comment: @PSN There is no `google_app_id` and there is no way to add debug key fingerprints in the Play Console ...the package name does not matter, the `google_app_id` looks whole different.

Comment: How to obtain the app_id?

Comment: this is how the output of the plugin looks alike: [processing the json file](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#processing_the_json_file).

Comment: I tried this https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials Credentials -> OAuth consent screen -> Scopes for Google APIs, and now it is closing. No errors are shown.

Comment: It's not an error. I finally logged in. Thank you for the detailed answer.